# Laravel composer issue with consolibyte

Tags: laravel, quickbooks

I want to use `consolibyte` in my laravel project.
So I did

```
composer require consolibyte/quickbooks
```

and then I did

```
compose update
```

But still I am not able to use the classes and constants of `consolibyte` in my project.

I also tried adding this

```
"files": ["vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks/QuickBooks.php"]
```

to the autoload section of the compose.json

and then I again did

```
composer update
```

but this I got an error

`QUICKBOOKS_TIMESTAMP is already defined`

Can I get some insight if I am missing something here?

Comment: Specifically what aren't you able to use? Exactly what error do you get when you try to use it? It sounds like everything is included, because the constants are defined...

Comment: The constants shows as undefined.
So I thought that I might need to change the composer.json. So I did that but faced other issues.
So do I need to make any change in the composer.json or it should work without it.

Comment: I think you need to post your code and the exact error messages. Your comments don't match what you said in your question -- in the comments you say the constants are undefined, but your question says "... is already defined" which means they _are_ defined...

Comment: I recreated the project and compose the library again and it worked after that.